# Pandas join/merge/concat two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues with joins in pandas and I am trying to figure out what is wrong. 
   Say I have a `dataframe` x:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1941 entries, 2004-10-19 00:00:00 to 2012-07-23 00:00:00
Data columns:
close    1941  non-null values
high     1941  non-null values
low      1941  non-null values
open     1941  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)
```

should I be able to join it with y on index with a simple join command where y = x except colnames have +2.

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 DatetimeIndex: 1941 entries, 2004-10-19 00:00:00 to 2012-07-23 00:00:00
 Data columns:
 close2    1941  non-null values
 high2     1941  non-null values
 low2      1941  non-null values
 open2     1941  non-null values
 dtypes: float64(4)

 y.join(x) or pandas.DataFrame.join(y,x):
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 DatetimeIndex: 34879 entries, 2004-12-16 00:00:00 to 2012-07-12 00:00:00
 Data columns:
 close2    34879  non-null values
 high2     34879  non-null values
 low2      34879  non-null values
 open2     34879  non-null values
 close     34879  non-null values
 high      34879  non-null values
 low       34879  non-null values
 open      34879  non-null values
 dtypes: float64(8)
```

I expect the final to have 1941 non-values for both. I tried merge as well but I have the same issue.

I had thought the right answer was pandas.concat([x,y]), but this does not do what I intend either.

```
In [83]: pandas.concat([x,y]) 
Out[83]: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
DatetimeIndex: 3882 entries, 2004-10-19 00:00:00 to 2012-07-23 00:00:00 
Data columns: 
close2 3882 non-null values 
high2 3882 non-null values 
low2 3882 non-null values 
open2 3882 non-null values 
dtypes: float64(4)
```

edit: 
If you are having issues with join, read Wes's answer below. I had one time stamp that was duplicated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does your index have duplicates `x.index.is_unique`? If so would explain the behavior you're seeing:

```
In [16]: left
Out[16]: 
            a
2000-01-01  1
2000-01-01  1
2000-01-01  1
2000-01-02  2
2000-01-02  2
2000-01-02  2

In [17]: right
Out[17]: 
            b
2000-01-01  3
2000-01-01  3
2000-01-01  3
2000-01-02  4
2000-01-02  4
2000-01-02  4

In [18]: left.join(right)
Out[18]: 
            a  b
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-01  1  3
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
2000-01-02  2  4
```

Answer (score 19):

It sounds like maybe you want `pandas.concat`?  `merge` and `join` do, well, joins, which means they will give you something based around the Cartesian product of the two inputs, but it sounds like you just want to paste them together into one big table.

Edit: did you try concat with `axis=1`?  It seems to do what you're asking for:

```
>>> print x
          A         B         C
0  0.155614 -0.252148  0.861163
1  0.973517  1.156465 -0.458846
2  2.504356 -0.356371 -0.737842
3  0.012994  1.785123  0.161667
4  0.574578  0.123689  0.017598
>>> print y
         A2        B2        C2
0 -0.280993  1.278750 -0.704449
1  0.140282  1.955322 -0.953826
2  0.581997 -0.239829  2.227069
3 -0.876146 -1.955199 -0.155030
4 -0.518593 -2.630978  0.333264
>>> print pandas.concat([x, y], axis=1)
          A         B         C        A2        B2        C2
0  0.155614 -0.252148  0.861163 -0.280993  1.278750 -0.704449
1  0.973517  1.156465 -0.458846  0.140282  1.955322 -0.953826
2  2.504356 -0.356371 -0.737842  0.581997 -0.239829  2.227069
3  0.012994  1.785123  0.161667 -0.876146 -1.955199 -0.155030
4  0.574578  0.123689  0.017598 -0.518593 -2.630978  0.333264
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I should have mentioned that I tried pandas.concat as well.

Comment: here is what concat looks like:

In [83]: pandas.concat([x,y])

Out[83]: 

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3882 entries, 2004-10-19 00:00:00 to 2012-07-23 00:00:00
Data columns:
close2    3882  non-null values
high2     3882  non-null values
low2      3882  non-null values
open2     3882  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)

Comment: Pasted output doesn't show up well in comments.  Can you edit your question to show an example of what your data is and what you want the output to be?

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for the help.  I must be missing something fundamental.

Comment: Thanks, there has to be something wrong with this dataframe.  I get the error:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: Not sure what that's about.  Try using what I suggested with a simple test dataframe.  If it works, then the problem is something specific to your data.