# How to merge two dataframes side-by-side?

Tags: python, pandas

is there a way to conveniently merge two data frames side by side?

both two data frames have 30 rows, they have different number of columns, say, df1 has 20 columns and df2 has 40 columns.

how can i easily get a new data frame of 30 rows and 60 columns?

```
df3 = pd.someSpecialMergeFunct(df1, df2)
```

or maybe there is some special parameter in append

```
df3 = pd.append(df1, df2, left_index=False, right_index=false, how='left')
```

ps: if possible, i hope the replicated column names could be resolved automatically.

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas join/merge/concat two dataframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637384/pandas-join-merge-concat-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 145):

You can use the `concat` function for this (`axis=1` is to concatenate as columns):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

See the pandas docs on merging/concatenating: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Have a look at this link - http://chris.friedline.net/2015-12-15-rutgers/lessons/python2/04-merging-data.html. And you might want to reset_index() before you concatenate them, in case you are not able to concatenate them side by side. This answer is correct. However, I just wanted to add a note for someone who might be stuck even after the answer.

Comment: @PallavBakshi Yes, I needed to add `.reset_index(drop=True)` to the dataframe on which I had done selection to realign the rows.

Comment: it may be more performant to change the list to a generator, this avoids creating a large intermediate object: `pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)`

Answer (score 13):

I came across your question while I was trying to achieve something like the following:

[image: Merge dataframe sideways]

So once I sliced my dataframes, I first ensured that their index are the same. In your case both dataframes needs to be indexed from 0 to 29. Then merged both dataframes by the index.

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True).merge(df2.reset_index(drop=True), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: best solution ever

Comment: Curious, why drop the indexes? `pd.merge(df_right, df_left on=df_left.index)`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to combine 2 data frames with common column name, you can do the following:

```
df_concat = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='common_column_name', how='outer')
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that the other answers didn't cut it for me when coming in from Google.

What I did instead was to set the new columns in place in the original df.

```
# list(df2) gives you the column names of df2
# you then use these as the column names for df

df[list(df2)] = df2
```

Answer (score 0):

- There is way, you can do it via a Pipeline.

** Use a pipeline to transform your numerical Data for ex-

```
Num_pipeline = Pipeline
([("select_numeric", DataFrameSelector([columns with numerical value])),
("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
])
```

**And for categorical data

```
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("select_cat", DataFrameSelector([columns with categorical data])),
    ("cat_encoder", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)),
])
```

** Then use a Feature union to add these transformations together

```
preprocess_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
    ("num_pipeline", num_pipeline),
    ("cat_pipeline", cat_pipeline),
])
```

- Read more here - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works if `df1` and `df2` have different indices:

```
df1.loc[:, df2.columns] = df2.to_numpy()
```