# How do I create a data frame and form two separate columns from these two outputs?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to have a dataframe that includes the following two outputs, side by side as columns:

```
finalcust = mainorder_df, custname1_df
print(finalcust)

finalcust
Out[46]: 
(10      10103.0
 26      10104.0
 39      10105.0
 54      10106.0
 72      10107.0
          ...   
 2932    10418.0
 2941    10419.0
 2955    10420.0
 2977    10424.0
 2983    10425.0
 Name: ordernumber, Length: 213, dtype: float64,
 1                  Signal Gift Stores
 2          Australian Collectors, Co.
 3                   La Rochelle Gifts
 4                  Baane Mini Imports
 5        Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd.
                     ...              
 117      Motor Mint Distributors Inc.
 118          Signal Collectibles Ltd.
 119    Double Decker Gift Stores, Ltd
 120              Diecast Collectables
 121                 Kelly's Gift Shop
 Name: customerName, Length: 91, dtype: object)
```

I have tried pd.merge but it says I am not allowed since there is no common column.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Apparently they have different lengths (first one has 2983 values, and the second one only 121). How do you intend to put them side-by-side in a data frame?

Comment: Did you try `pd.concat(finalcust, axis=1)`? Note that it joins by the *index* of the 2 Series

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to accomplish?

#### General Merging with `df.merge()`

The data frames cannot be merged because they are not related in anyway. Pandas expects them to have a similar column in order to know how to merge. [pandas.DataFrame.merge docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

**Example**: If you wanted to take information from a customer information sheet and add it to an order list.

```
import pandas as pd
customers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
addresses = ['Adress_A', 'Address_B', 'Address_C', 'Address_D']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': customers,
                     'Info': addresses})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A','B','C','D','A','B'],
                     'Order': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df = df1.merge(df2)
df =

Customer    Info    Order
0   A   Adress_A    1
1   A   Adress_A    5
2   A   Adress_A    9
3   B   Address_B   2
4   B   Address_B   6
5   B   Address_B   10
6   C   Address_C   3
7   C   Address_C   7
8   D   Address_D   4
9   D   Address_D   8
```

#### Combining with `df.concat()`

If they were the same size, you would use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine them. There is a post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891575/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-side-by-side)

**Example**: Adding a new list of customers to the customer df

```
import pandas as pd
customers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
addresses = ['Address_A', 'Address_B', 'Address_C', 'Address_D']
new_customers = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
new_addresses = ['Address_E', 'Address_F', 'Address_G', 'Address_G']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': customers,
                     'Info': addresses})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': new_customers,
                     'Info': new_addresses})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df =
    Customer    Info
0   A   Address_A
1   B   Address_B
2   C   Address_C
3   D   Address_D
0   E   Address_E
1   F   Address_F
2   G   Address_G
3   H   Address_G
```

#### Combining "Side by Side" by Adding a New Column

The side by side method of combination would be adding a column.

**Example:** Adding a new column to customer information df.

```
import pandas as pd
customers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
addresses = ['Address_A', 'Address_B', 'Address_C', 'Address_D']
phones = [1,2,3,4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': customers,
                     'Info': addresses})
df['Phones'] = phones
df =
Customer    Info    Phones
0   A   Address_A   1
1   B   Address_B   2
2   C   Address_C   3
3   D   Address_D   4
```

#### Actually Doing...?

If you are trying to assign a customer name to an order, that can't be done with the data you have here.

Hope this helps..