# how to expand the below dataframs in pandas or numpy based on interval_start and interval_end

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, numpy

How do I expand the below dataframs in pandas or numpy based on **interval_start** and **interval_end**

Few of the examples i have tried but missing last few days of month.

Input DF :

```
+--------------+------------+----+---+
|interval_start|interval_end|name|val|
+--------------+------------+----+---+
|2018-10-31    |2020-09-05  | abc|1  |
|2020-09-05    |2020-10-05  | abc|1  |
|2020-01-31    |2020-04-30  | def|2  |
+--------------+------------+----+---+
```

From the Input DF split the dataframe based the two columns interval_start and interval_end with a sequence of dates between them as shown in the output DF

Output DF:

```
+--------------+------------+----+---+
|interval_start|interval_end|name|val|
+--------------+------------+----+---+
|2018-10-31    |2018-11-30  | abc|1  |
|2018-11-30    |2018-12-31  | abc|1  |
|2018-12-31    |2019-01-31  | abc|1  |
|2019-01-31    |2019-02-28  | abc|1  |
|2019-02-28    |2019-03-31  | abc|1  |
|2019-03-31    |2019-04-30  | abc|1  |
|2019-04-30    |2019-05-31  | abc|1  |
|2019-05-31    |2019-06-30  | abc|1  |
|2019-06-30    |2019-07-31  | abc|1  |
|2019-07-31    |2019-08-31  | abc|1  |
|2019-08-31    |2019-09-30  | abc|1  |
|2019-09-30    |2019-10-31  | abc|1  |
|2019-10-31    |2019-11-30  | abc|1  |
|2019-11-30    |2019-12-31  | abc|1  |
|2019-12-31    |2020-01-31  | abc|1  |
|2020-01-31    |2020-02-29  | abc|1  |
|2020-02-29    |2020-03-31  | abc|1  |
|2020-03-31    |2020-04-30  | abc|1  |
|2020-04-30    |2020-05-31  | abc|1  |
|2020-05-31    |2020-06-30  | abc|1  |
|2020-06-30    |2020-07-31  | abc|1  |
|2020-07-31    |2020-08-31  | abc|1  |
|2020-08-31    |2020-09-05  | abc|1  |
|2020-09-05    |2020-10-05  | abc|1  |
|2020-01-31    |2020-02-29  | def|2  |
|2020-02-29    |2020-03-31  | def|2  |
|2020-03-31    |2020-04-30  | def|2  |
+--------------+------------+----+---+
```

Comment: I think this is already answered. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891575/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-side-by-side

For extra information you can use this link:
http://chris.friedline.net/2015-12-15-rutgers/lessons/python2/04-merging-data.html

Comment: No,this is completely different

Comment: Then I don't understand what has to happen to the input df in order to get the output. Can you try to explain that in more details?

Comment: From date 2018-10-31 to 2020-09-05 need to expand the dataframe with one month interval based on the interval_start and interval_end

Answer (score 0):

Oke that makes sense. This code is giving you the expected results

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset 
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
import datetime 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
   {
        "interval_start": ["2018-10-31", "2020-09-05", "2020-01-31"],
        "interval_end": ["2020-09-05", "2020-10-05", "2020-04-30"],
        "name": ["abc", "abc", "def"],
        "val": ["1", "1", "2"],
    },
index=[0, 1, 2],
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame()
start_list = []
end_list = []
name_list = []
val_list = []
for i in range(3):
    interval = pd.period_range(df1["interval_start"][i], df1["interval_end"][i], freq="M")
    date_plus1 = datetime.datetime.strptime((df1["interval_start"][i] ), '%Y-%m-%d' ) + relativedelta(months=+1)
    
    for k in range(len(interval)):
        start_list.append(str(pd.period_range(df1["interval_start"][i], df1["interval_end"][i], freq="M")[k]) + str(-30))
        end_list.append(str(date_plus1)[0:10])
        name_list.append(df1["name"][i])
        val_list.append(df1["val"][i])
        
        date_plus1 = date_plus1 + relativedelta(months=+1)

df2["interval_start"] = start_list
df2["interval_end"] = end_list
df2["name"] = name_list
df2["val"] = val_list

print(df2)
```

You only have to play around a bit with the dates if you want the exact last date of the every month.