# How to combine multiple csv as columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have 10 .txt (csv) files that I want to merge together in a single csv file to use later in analysis. when I use  **pd.append**, it always merges the files below each other.

I use the following code:

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        files = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', skiprows=[1])
        master_df = master_df.append(files)
```

the output is:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8o2p.jpg)

what I need is to insert the columns of each file side-by-side, as follows:

[The required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv3Rb.jpg)

could you please help with this?

Comment: Checkout: [How to merge two dataframes side-by-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891575/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-side-by-side)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge DataFrames side by side, you should use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```
frames = []

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        files = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', skiprows=[1])
        frames.append(files)

# axis = 0 has the same behavior of your original approach
master_df = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1)
```