# Python pandas merge or concat dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of csv which I load into dataframes and store in a list (dataframesArray).  The list and dataframes looks like the follow:

```
    dataframesArray [            
    BBG.XAMS.UL.S_pnl_pos_cost
        date                                  
        2015-03-23                    0.000000
        2015-03-24                    0.000000
        2015-03-25                   -0.674717
        2015-03-26                   69.140999
        2015-03-27                  -70.128728,             
    BBG.XAMS.UNA.S_pnl_pos_cost
        date                                   
        2015-03-23                    -0.674929
        2015-03-24                   -15.138444
        2015-03-25                    90.830662
        2015-03-26                    21.446129
        2015-03-27                    -2.554376,             
    BBG.XAMS.UL.S_pnl_pos_cost
        date                                  
        2014-10-20                  -15.220730
        2014-10-21                 3031.610010
        2014-10-22                 1976.815412
        2014-10-23                -2974.037294
        2014-10-24                  796.775000,
   BBG.XAMS.UNA.S_pnl_pos_cost
        date                                   
        2014-10-20                    -4.140378
        2014-10-21                   618.064066
        2014-10-22                   -71.104800
        2014-10-23                   828.063647
        2014-10-24                     0.000000]
```

The data is for 2 products (BBG.XAMS.UL.S_pnl_pos_cost and BBG.XAMS.UNA.S_pnl_pos_cost) by date, in the future there will be more products.  I want to concat or merge (not sure which) the list of dataframes into one data frame (called result)so they look like:

```
            BBG.XAMS.UL.S_pnl_pos_cost  BBG.XAMS.UNA.S_pnl_pos_cost  date                                                                  
2014-10-20                 -15.220730                     -4.140378   
2014-10-21                3031.610010                    618.064066   
2014-10-22                1976.815412                    -71.104800   
2014-10-23               -2974.037294                    828.063647   
2014-10-24                 796.775000                      0.000000   
2015-03-23                    0.000000                    -0.674929   
2015-03-24                    0.000000                   -15.138444   
2015-03-25                   -0.674717                    90.830662   
2015-03-26                   69.140999                    21.446129   
2015-03-27                  -70.128728                    -2.554376
```

I am trying to do this with the following:

```
result = pd.concat(dataframesArray,axis=1)
```

where axis is the date.  It looks like the data is merged by date, but I am missing the data for the week beginning 2015-03-23.  My current concat result dataframe looks like:

```
BBG.XAMS.UL.S_pnl_pos_cost  BBG.XAMS.UNA.S_pnl_pos_cost  
date                                                                 
2014-10-20                  -15.220730                    -4.140378  
2014-10-21                 3031.610010                   618.064066  
2014-10-22                 1976.815412                   -71.104800  
2014-10-23                -2974.037294                   828.063647  
2014-10-24                  796.775000                     0.000000  
2015-03-23                         NaN                          NaN  
2015-03-24                         NaN                          NaN  
2015-03-25                         NaN                          NaN  
2015-03-26                         NaN                          NaN  
2015-03-27                         NaN                          NaN
```

my code at present is:

```
stockPricesDf=pd.read_csv(f,engine='c',header=0,index_col=0, parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True,usecols=(0,3))

                stockPricesDf.rename(columns={'adjusted_last_acc': row},inplace=True)    

                dataframesArray.append(stockPricesDf) 

                result = pd.concat(dataframesArray,axis=1)
```

I am looping though some directories to obtain the product data which is stored in csv files.

Could someone please let me know what I've done wrong and how to fix

Many thanks

Comment: Try using axis=0. This should concat column-wise, assuming each dataframe has the same column names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas join/merge/concat two dataframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637384/pandas-join-merge-concat-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = pd.concat(dataframesArray, axis=1) # like you did
result = result.groupby(result.columns, axis=1).sum()
```

As you saw, the first step does this (made up numbers):

```
                  UL       UNA        UL       UNA
2015-03-23  2.169534  0.294107       NaN       NaN
2015-03-24 -0.077550 -0.758760       NaN       NaN
2015-03-25  0.159659 -3.167541       NaN       NaN
2015-03-26  0.895535  0.944644       NaN       NaN
2015-03-27 -0.385408 -0.005069       NaN       NaN
2015-10-20       NaN       NaN  1.855446 -0.229635
2015-10-21       NaN       NaN -0.400450 -0.237323
2015-10-22       NaN       NaN  1.103165  0.718134
2015-10-23       NaN       NaN -0.157415  1.119828
2015-10-24       NaN       NaN -0.016321 -0.371061
```

The second step will group columns sharing the same name into a single column:

```
                  UL       UNA
2015-03-23  2.169534  0.294107
2015-03-24 -0.077550 -0.758760
2015-03-25  0.159659 -3.167541
2015-03-26  0.895535  0.944644
2015-03-27 -0.385408 -0.005069
2015-10-20  1.855446 -0.229635
2015-10-21 -0.400450 -0.237323
2015-10-22  1.103165  0.718134
2015-10-23 -0.157415  1.119828
2015-10-24 -0.016321 -0.371061
```

Comment: Thank you Ian, that hit the spot