# merging 2 dataframes vertically

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframes that have 2 columns each (same column names). I want to merge them vertically to end up having a new dataframe.

When doing

```
newdf = df.merge(df1,how='left',on=['Col1','Col2'])
```

The new df has only the rows from `df` and none of the rows from `df1`. Any reasons why this might happen?

```
Col1    Col2
asd     1232
cac     2324
.....
```

and the `df1` is:

```
Col1    Col2
afaf    1213
asas    4353
```

The new dataframe `newdf` should be:

```
Col1   Col2
asd     1232
cac     2324
afaf    1213
asas    4353
```

Comment: you want `pd.concat([df1,df2])`, this is a very common question, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637384/pandas-join-merge-concat-two-dataframes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819050/pandas-dataframe-concat-vs-append

Comment: I forgot to mention that concat returns:TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: when you pass `how='left'` this only merge's horizontally on the values in those columns on the lhs, it's unclear what you really want. You can try passing 'outer'

Answer (score 98):

You could use `append` and use `ignore_index` if you don't want to use the index values as is.

```
In [14]: df1.append(df2)
Out[14]:
   Col1  Col2
0   asd  1232
1   cac  2324
0  afaf  1213
1  asas  4353

In [15]: df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
Out[15]:
   Col1  Col2
0   asd  1232
1   cac  2324
2  afaf  1213
3  asas  4353
```

or use `pd.concat`

```
In [16]: pd.concat([df1, df2])
Out[16]:
   Col1  Col2
0   asd  1232
1   cac  2324
0  afaf  1213
1  asas  4353

In [17]: pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
Out[17]:
   Col1  Col2
0   asd  1232
1   cac  2324
2  afaf  1213
3  asas  4353
```

Comment: append takes lesser time than merge.

Comment: if i want to vertically concat more than 2 dataframes, can i still use this ?

Comment: You can use `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1)` to concat vertically.

Comment: `Concat` is preferred per the warning: `FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.`