# merge two similar data and sum the value using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

how do I merge and sum`` genre1 and genre2 total movie?

```
genre1= movie_overavg.groupby('genre_1',as_index=False)['movie_title'].count()
genre1.columns=['genre','total movie']
genre1=genre1.set_index('genre')
print(genre1)


genre3= movie_overavg.groupby('genre_3',as_index=False)['movie_title'].count()
genre3.columns=['genre','total movie']
genre3=genre3.set_index('genre')
```

[image: genre1]

[image: genre2]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41181829/8353711). Concat data vertically and apply `groupby` as you did.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets say

df = table 1

```
    genre   total
0   action      450
1   adventure   200
2   animation   300
3   crime       10
```

df2 = table 2

```
genre   total
0   action      450
1   adventure   200
2   animation   300
```

these can be done by

```
f = [df, df2]

result = pd.concat(f)
new_df = result.groupby('genre')['total'].sum().reset_index()
```

output

```
genre        total
0   action       900
1   adventure    400
2   animation    600
3   crime        10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
df = genre1.add(genre3, fill_value=0)
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) wth aggregate `size`:

```
s = pd.concat([movie_overavg['genre_1'], movie_overavg['genre_3']])

df = s.value_counts().sort_index().to_frame('total movie')
```

---

```
df = s.groupby(s).size().to_frame('total movie')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(genre1, genre2, on=['genre']).set_index(['genre']).sum(axis=1)
```