# How to combine two dataframes (same shape, including NaN)?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, nan

I want to combine `df1` and `df2` to get `df3`.

`df1` and `df2` will have the exact same `index` and `column` (same shape), including some `np.NaN`.  They will have no overlapping values (no ambiguity).  Take the value if it's there in either one.

**What is the most direct way to do this?**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.0, np.NaN], 'B':[np.NaN, np.NaN]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.NaN, np.NaN], 'B':[np.NaN, 0.0]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.0, np.NaN], 'B':[np.NaN, 0.0]})
```

I've tried `df1 + df2`, `df1 | df2`, and looked into `merge()` but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Suppose I do a `replace(0,magicNumber)` and then a `replace(np.NaN, 0)`.  Then I can add the two dataframes and then do a `replace(magicNumber, 0)`.  But this is very ugly, obfuscating code.  If there's a cleaner, pandomic/pythonic solution, please do let me know.  Thx.

Comment: You may want to look at this post [Pandas join/merge/concat two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637384/pandas-join-merge-concat-two-dataframes)

Comment: @SidKwakkel Thanks, but not the same kind of issue I am having.

Comment: @kfmfe04  Let me know if any further clarification needed.  Please consider to accept the answer if it is fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:  `df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)`

See the document [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first)

Comment: Excellent!  Seems to work great.  I'll let this post sit for a day or two and then accept.  TY.